# How secure are singletons in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, security, thread-safety, singleton

Are singletons in ASP.NET shared between users/sessions? And if they are, are there any safety considerations? Think serializing/deserializing vulnerabilities, thread safety etc.

Is it the way to go using settings from the database that are the same for all users?

Answer (score 1):

Hand crafting the anti-pattern called "Singleton" in C# code is a really bad idea in general, ASP.NET or not.

The *singleton lifetime* that is supported in the dependency injection framework is a good idea if it does what you need.

I would advise you to only use it for read-only data, like settings, though. You don't have an application on the desktop as of old. Your application might be recycled on the fly, or maybe stretched across multiple nodes on a server farm. So suddenly your "singleton" is actually only a singleton if you have a single instance of your program running. Building your application so this becomes an artificial problem (i.e. the framework would support it, but your own code is build to fail if you actually do so) is not a smart way to go about this.

So to summarize: Singleton lifetime in your dependency injection container? Might be okay. Depends on your use case. An actual "Singleton" pattern in your code? Bad. Very Bad. Tells me you don't actually do any unit testing and nothing is planned to bring this application over a few thousand hobbyist users who don't care if your app is down every time you deploy.